# How to capture a slide.moveto event in vsto 2010

Tags: c#, event-handling, vsto, powerpoint

I'm creating a powerpoint addin - where a specific function are called whenever I add a new slide to the presentation.
For this I'm using the `Application.PresentationNewSlide` event
But I would also like capture when the user moves an existing slide.
Does anyone know the event for `slide.MoveTo` ?

Comment: There's no MoveTo event.  You'll probably have to trap Selection Change events and if the selection is a slide or slide range, track what changes occur in slide order.  I'm guessing that you'd have to maintain an array of SlideID & SlideIndex of the slides in the presentation.  SlideID will never change, but SlideIndex will.